# How can i access an array inside array containing product object in javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays

Hey Fellow stackoverflowers, recently i got a new problem accessing array inside array and that inside array containg two objects product and quantity. Now i want to access that inside array how can i do that. Please if you have any solution please share with me:

```
const arrayOfArrays = [
 [
   { product: { name: 'Product 1', price: 10 }, quantity: 1 },
   { product: { name: 'Product 2', price: 20 }, quantity: 2 }
 ]
];
```

Comment: what do you want access exactly?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4968406/javascript-property-access-dot-notation-vs-brackets — `arrayOfArrays[0]` will get you the inside array

Answer (score 0):

you need first to take 0th element of outer array, then you can enumerate internal array, like this:

```js
const arrayOfArrays = [
 [
   { product: { name: 'Product 1', price: 10 }, quantity: 1 },
   { product: { name: 'Product 2', price: 20 }, quantity: 2 }
 ]
];

console.log(arrayOfArrays[0][0].product.name);
console.log(arrayOfArrays[0][1].product.name);
```

Answer (score -2):

const innerArray = arrayOfArrays[0];

// Accessing the first element of the inner array
const firstElement = innerArray[0];

// Accessing the product name of the first element
const productName = firstElement.product.name;

console.log(productName);